# Use area name to get pincode/postalcode in android?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps, android-maps-v2

In my app,getting address from user,after user enter the area name how to display the pin code/postal code automatically in edit text field.using map any one know please share with me.

Comment: Look into https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/

Comment: what do u mean by automatically, do u mean like when u type on google text field, a suggesion is shown there(like this u want to perform)?